# Does performance of an event handler depends on the number of child elements

Tags: javascript, performance, event-bubbling, event-handling

I've got a single mousedown event handler on a table with dynamically increasing number of rows (right now over thousand, in perspective should have been unlimited) and I observe a drop down in performance as the number of preloaded rows increases. The purpose of event handler is simple - figure out which row was clicked and highlight it.

I do not know exactly what causes the slowdown and I'm not sure if it's event handler. I just wonder if number of child elements that could trigger mousedown bubble can affect the performance of an event handler attached to single parent element?

**Update:** I came up with simple example here: http://client.infinity-8.me/table.php?num=1000 (you can pass whatever number you want to num), basically it renders a table with num rows and has a single event handler attached to a parent table. I should conclude from this, that there actually is no noticeable dropdown in performance, caused by number of child elements.

Comment: maybe post an url to see what really slows you down.

Comment: most importantly: the page behaves slow, or the event handling lasts too long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it shouldn't. Only deepness should matter, since bubbling goes up by checking handlers on every level (one per level).

It performs great with **10 000** elements **even on IE6**.

[**See it in action**](http://jsbin.com/ibobu/3/).